# Parent nodes not rendering when using 'cola' layout

Tags: cytoscape.js

I was hoping to use parent nodes with the cytoscape.js 'cola' layout.

When changing the 'Compound nodes' demo's layout from 'cose' to 'cola', the 'b' and 'e' parents do not render.

The cola.js home site has examples showing parent-like features.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you encountered a bug.  If you encounter a bug in future, please file one in the issue tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues

Specific issue : https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/878